# How to create the rounded corner button using css file?

Tags: asp.net, css

how to create rounded corner button using css file and how this css file apply in button.
please give the css code for that

Comment: This solution worked for me "http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/383627/How-to-Create-Rounded-Corners-Textbox-in-Asp-Net-U"

Answer (score 5):

use **border-radius** for IE , **-moz-border-radius** for Firefox and **-webkit-border-radius** for safari

```
#example1 {
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px; }
```

For Reference http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Answer (score 2):

Specify the corners you want:

```
border-top-left-radius: 10px 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10% 5%;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
```

[Border-radius: create rounded corners with CSS!](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/)

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS [border-radius](http://parrot-tutorial.com/cssref/border-radius.html) property to create rounded corner buttons.

```css
.btn {
   display: inline-block;
   border: 1px solid transparent;
   border-radius: 24px;
   padding: 12px 32px;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: pointer;
   font-size: 1rem;
   color: #fff;
}

.btn-blue  {background-color: #007bff;}
.btn-green {background-color: #28a745;}
.btn-red   {background-color: #dc3545;}
.btn-grey  {background-color: #6c757d;}

/* Change bg-color on mouse over  */
.btn-blue:hover  {background-color: #0069d9;}
.btn-green:hover {background-color: #218838;}
.btn-red:hover   {background-color: #c82333;}
.btn-grey:hover  {background-color: #5a6268;}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-blue">Blue</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-green">Green</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-red">Red</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-grey">Grey</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean with a button. But this is the CSS:

```
.button {
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Just give your button the class button

Here is some more info on border-radius:
[Border radius Css3files](http://www.css3files.com/border/#borderradius)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [border-radius](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/) CSS property to set this up.

See [here for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fermin/BEDTm/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer is a lot simpler.

This is the following code used:

```
<html>
<style>
.btn {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 2px 2px;
    background-color: DarkOliveGreen;
}
</style>
<a href="http://google.com" class="btn">test</a>
<html>
```

this button is a hyperlink with padding and border radius. Much simpler

Comment: please comment if this helped you