# How to create color full rounded corner navigation menu using css

Tags: asp.net, css

In asp.net How to create color full rounded corner navigation menu using css and whenever user click on parent node then all the child node wiil be display and color of the parent node will be change.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122620/how-to-create-the-rounded-corner-button-using-css-file ?

Answer (score 1):

CSS Rounded corners are done using the `border-radius` style. It's widely supported in all browsers now, but you may need to add some vendor prefixes to support older versions of browsers.

IE8 and lower does not support `border-radius` at all, but can be made to do so using various hacks, of which [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) is by far the best. (IE9 does support it just fine though)

For menus that change colour and drop down the submenu when you mouse-over, you can use the `:hover` CSS selector.

So something like this:

.menu {background-color:red;}
   .menu:hover {background-color:blue;}

Of course there's more to it than that, especially when you're talking about drop-down menus, but that's the basic stylesheet functionality you need to know.

There's a whole bunch of tutorials for this on the web, but this looks like a good one: http://divitodesign.com/css/how-to-dropdown-css-menu/

If you want to do it on *click* rather than hover, you might find you have do some of the work with Javascript rather than pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use  [ajax Rounded Corners](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/RoundedCorners/RoundedCorners.aspx) or you can use rounded images. There are loads of jquery dropdown menus available on net